# UWP: Max-Space for Textbox

Tags: win-universal-app

I have a TextBox in a Stackpanel in a Flyout.
When I enter Text in that TextBox the text scrolls horiziontal when it is larger than the Textbox' width.
When I press Enter the rest of the Text is not visible.

How can I fix the maximum horizontal Text so it breaks at the right border of the TextBox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [TextWrapping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.textwrapping.aspx) property

```
 <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I was looking for - thank you! But why can't I choose WrapWholeWords (VS Intellisense offers that). I then get the error "Wrong Parameter..." (E_RUNTIME_SETVALUE)

Comment: Not sure of the E_RUNTIME_SETVALUE error. use Accept return as true to accept return key to insert a new line in input text. 
<TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True"/>

Comment: @StefanMeyer Not sure of that.. I ll let you know if I get the reason

Comment: See this explanation from MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.textwrapping